# SharePoint Online - Office 365 - Help to clearing up some issues and some inspiration/guiding

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, office, office-365-developer

I have been employed by a company that uses Office 365 Enterprise E3

They are not completely satisfied with their SharePoint solution and for good reason.
Technically it works but the appearance looks more like a "Windows Explorer with a website". Users use the most as a FileShare and that's it. For example, make a document - upload it and sends an email around if there are others who would be interested in it.
I am not an expert in SharePoint but believes that SharePoint can do much more than that
The company is a consulting company with offices in several cities and are not divided traditionally structured as an organization (sales - marketing, economy , finance,  development etc) but more as independent offices in different cities

They want to use SharePoint as a knowledge and collobaration center.

First, I think - aha they need an intranet with team sites. But is it possible with their chosen solution?

If so - will it be a starting point to base the team sites on individual cities (eg city 1 city 2, city 3 etc.) and then create a structure for a single city.?

Can you possibly. guide me to the examples / tutorials on building intranet team sites?

Which version of SharePoint, Office 365 features (is it SharePoint 2016?)

Can you develop new design / new apps / new structure?

Can you, with advantage, use the Office UI Fabric, or should developng by the hardcore use of Visual Studio?

What about Sharepoint Designer?

The company would like to use Yammer as a social medium.
Can you use Yammer as a news feed for SharePoint
If yes - Is there a guide / tutorial on integrating Yammer with Office 365/Sharepoint?

I do not have the opportunity to work on their server, as I am afraid to crashed it
I have therefore signed up for a trial (30 days) of their solution Office 365 Enterprise E3.

But get stucked because you obviously have to install Office 2016 on your computer.
But this is not possigle (for me) since I already bought and paid for an Office Professional Plus 2013. It should then be uninstalled first.
My computer is shared among multiple users (my family) who daily use Office and in principle I only need to use SharePoint.
Is it possible to try a trial of SharePoint Online that corresponds to the version included Office 365?

As mentioned earlier, I am not an expert in SharePoint and have only worked with SharePoint 2010 on-premises

Is there anyone who can help to clarify these issues

Comment: This question is really 5-10 individual question, many of which are primarly opinion-based. Therefore it will be closed

Comment: Ok if it has to many possible answers then it would be nice if you could answer some of the questions. If it has some opinion issues then dont answer them.
But to closed the question is not going to help me or others.. I just need some direction to get started to use Sharepoint Online in a proper way.

If this is not the rigth fora to ask these questins,  maybe you  could provide me with a URl  for the right and helpfull discussion board?

Comment: Hi there, it is closed because it is not living up to the standards of this community, please take the "newbie" tour here to learn more http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/tour . What you should do is to reask the questions that are not primarly opinion-based as new, separate questions to conform to the format och this community